# Finding intersection between a quadratic equation and linear equation

Tags: quadratics

Is it possible that you find a quadratic equation that NEVER intersects the linear equation y=x?

I believe that it is impossible. I tried as many equations as I could such as y=(x+10)^2 and x=(y+10)^2, yet there seems to be none that do not intersect the equation.

Comment: Welcome to stackexhange. Please edit the question to show what you tried. Hint: try sketching a suitable parabola. If you answer your own question you can post an answer yourself.

Comment: Over the real numbers this is possible.   Over the complex numbers, no, it is not possible.  So please clarify the context of your Question.

Comment: Is $y=x^2+1$ admitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Surely y=(x+5)^2 will work...]

`y=x` and `y=(x+5)^2` do not intersect

Comment: If this response is wrong it is clearly due to lack of clarity in the question ;)

Comment: The OP casts significant doubt by claiming to have tried $y=(x+10)^2$ and $x=(y+10)^2$ unsuccessfully.